# Scene Kit override SCNNode rendering

Tags: scenekit

I,ve checked out Scene Kit which looks pretty easy to use. There is a way to override a SCNNode's rendering, which is fine. 
The problem is the I would like to render additional elements next to the default rendering.
When I override the rendering in SCNNodeRendererDelegate, it no longer renders for example the geometry attached to it.
Lets say I would like to render the geometry's wireframe, a bounding box, or 2dtext on top.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What about adding a child node and setting the node's rendering delegate to this child node?
Then access the parent node / geometry etc.. from the renderer delegate method with [node parentNode]

Comment: it would be a nice workaround which could be used, for example to add a bounding box by accessing the parent node's geometry. But it still not working to draw a wireframe. At least not as easy. because I still have to use my own implemetation drawing the wire, instead simply overriding the opengl attributes to draw wire.

Answer (score 0):

As written in [rendererDelegate docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408012-rendererdelegate)

> [SceneKit] tells **your delegate** to draw contents for the node

And at the very bottom, the solution for your problem is described

> If you instead want to customize the results of SceneKit’s geometry and material rendering, use the SCNShadable protocol to attach shaders to SceneKit objects.

So you should take a look at [SCNShadable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadable)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

might be a silly question but did you try calling the original method with super first?

```
- (void)renderNode:(SCNNode *)node renderer:(SCNRenderer *)renderer arguments:(NSDictionary *)arguments{
    [super renderNode:node renderer:renderer arguments:arguments];
    //... then your stuff here....

}
```

Comment: There is no original method, this is a delegate callback and super is whatever you set as delegate.